# Increment function isnt working properly- Can't find the error (Java, for-loops)

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

I am to make a word game that takes in a users input. If the users String contains certain letters, they will be assigned a certain score. In the end I am to report what the persons String was, and what their score was. For example, given the input: "Hello", the persons score should be "8". (h= 4 points, e= 1 point, l= 1 point, 1= 1 point, 0= 1 point). You will be able to see all the score rules to the letters in my code below. I tested this algorithm on JGrasp, and it is giving me the score of my last letter only, which I'm confused about since I incremented my score variable. So, when I input "Hello", it's giving me a score of "1" instead of "8". Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    String curLine= scan.nextLine();
    int score=0;
    int[] value= {1,2,3,4,5,8,10};
    for(int k= 0; k < curLine.length(); k++){
    char c= curLine.charAt(k);
    if(c == 'b'||c== 'c'|| c=='m'||c=='p'){
    score= value[2];
    }
    else if(c=='d'||c=='g'){
    score= value[1];
    }
    else if(c=='f'||c=='h'||c=='v'||c=='w'||c=='y'){
    score= value[3];
    }
    else if(c=='j'||c=='x'){
    score=value[5];
    }
    else if(c=='k'){
    score=value[4];
    }
    else if(c=='q'||c=='z'){
    score=value[6];
    }
    else{
    score=value[0];
    }
    }
    System.out.println("Your string was: " + curLine + "Your score is: " + score++);
    }
    }
```

Comment: all you need is for example instead of score= value[2]; -> score+= value[2]; which means score= score + value[2];

Answer (score 0):

You are always (re-)setting the value of `score` in each branch:

```
score=value[index];
```

That means your score will always have the value assigned to the last character of your input string only (in your case "o" --> "1").

You need to sum up the values instead:

```
score+=value[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values to `score` variable every time. You need to add the value with the existing `score`. Like following

```
score+=value[index];
```

Comment: Ahhh, okay thank you that makes sense. I made the adjustment, but now it's giving me a score of "5" instead of "8". Do you think it's counting the 1 only once? For the String "Hello", H is worth 4 points, while the rest are worth 1 point. Is it counting the 4 and 1 point instead of counting the 4 and the three 1 points?

Comment: Nevermind, the H was a capital letter while the rest were lowercase. It wasn't counting the uppercase letter, thank you anyways!